# How to use a mongoose model in another model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, model

I have the two following models. In the user model I want to use an array of Requests and in Request Model I want to use User as an attribute(without the password). How can I do it?

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
  cartaoCidadao: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: {
      unique: true,
    },
    match: /[0-9]{8}/,
  },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  role: { type: String },

  estado: { type: String, enum: ["Infetado", "Suspeito"] },
});

var requestSchema = new Schema({
  encaminhado: { type: String },
  pessoaRisco: { type: String },
  trabalhoRisco: { type: String },
  estadoPedido: { type: String },
  resultado: { type: String },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the schema you defined as a type itself:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    // ...
    requests: {
        type: [requestSchema] // this property type is: array of requests
    }
    // ...
});
```

If both models are stored in database and you probably want to go for their association. You can reference one model from another. (see the answer of Muhammad Lahin)

Then you query your parent model and associate the children models with it (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

And here is an example of how you can exclude some fields during the population:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions

It will be something like:

```
User.
  find(/* some query */).
  populate({
    path: 'requests',
    select: 'fieldToSelect1 fieldToSelect2' // You can control which fields to include
  }).
  exec();
```

Comment: but how do I hide the password? For example, if a user does a request to be tested I don´t want that the doctor sees his password

Comment: so if I want to see a request data I do
Request.findOneByID({_id:id},(req,res,next){
   find(user.id).
   populate({ 
        path:user
    select:cartaoCidadao,estado

Comment: yes, this will fetch your request entity and populate the inner user entity and if applying the select - it will only include in the user the specified fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the type of the user in the request model like this

```
  type: schema.Types.ObjectID,
  ref: 'users'
```

which users id schema of users and when you want to send the whole user data in the response, use  populate and in populate you can omit the password too

now if you see the mondodb database in the request database the whole user object is not saved and only the user_id is saved so you dont have access to the user. you have to send another request to get the user data from the gived user_id which is not good. the solution is you set the schema as I said and when you are sending a response which have the data of the request use populate to add the userdata to the response

```
res.json({request: requests.find(//options to find a specified request).populate('users','name')})
```

first argument is the model which is users and the second argument is the wanted field of the users model for example this will return the name of the user. you can add more arguments to add all of them except the password

Comment: I didn´t understand the populate part

Comment: I think I understanded it . So i store the userID. So for example ,when I want to see the requests of a user , I use the method populate in my controller ,right?

Comment: I am having trouble adding more than one attributte

Comment: you can have multiple populates like ....populate().populate().populate()

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    requests: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Request",
        }
    ]
});

var requestSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     user: {
            type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
            ref:  'User'
           }
});
```